# CardLayout: Find out if current Item is first/last in list

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I use CardLayout and want to use two Buttons with .next() and .previous() to scroll through the Items. It works great with only one problem: I want to stop scrolling if the current Item is the first/last Item.

I can't find a Method to get the Index of the current Item or a flag to find out wether the current Item is first/last or not.

Can you tell me a simple way to find out if the current item is the first/last?

Since there are the methods .first() and .last() to jump, i guessed there must be a method to find out if the current is the first/last.

Comment: `I. Actually i extended CardLayout, overriding several methods` - would be nice if you shared your solution for other who have the same question.

Comment: I looked at the code provided by camickr and think his is actually better than mine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply use a `List<String>` containing all the names of the components in the card layout, and a field containing the index of the currently displayed component.

To know if you're at the beginning, you would test if `index == 0`. To know if you're at the last component, you would test if `index == list.size() - 1`. To show the next component, you would use `index++; layout.show(parent, list.get(index));`.

Comment: Thank you for that hint. Actually i extended CardLayout, overriding several methods and now it works just fine:)

Answer (score 2):

> i extended CardLayout, overriding several methods

That was my solution as well. See [Card Layout Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/card-layout-focus/) for my implementation.